Issue with POST Request in Next.js 14 via WAF in Production Environment
I am working on a project with Next.js 14 using the App Router. I encountered an issue where POST requests do not work in the production environment, but everything works fine in both the local and testing environments.
The production environment is set up as follows: I make requests to the WAF at testdomain.com, which, through a load balancer, redirects the requests to the less loaded server: either testdomain1.com or testdomain2.com. If I bypass the WAF and directly access the servers (testdomain1.com or testdomain2.com), everything works correctly.
I don’t understand the cause of the issue or how to resolve it: is it related to Next.js configuration or specific WAF settings? I’m attaching the error logs for further analysis:
TypeError: Invalid URL
at new URL (node:internal/url:775:36)
at rE (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:15:6577)
at r7 (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:18:1150)
at C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:19:726
at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
at Object.wrap (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:13:17831)
at C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:19:616
at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
at Object.wrap (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:13:16935)
at ne (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:19:543)
at nx.render (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:19:4561)
at doRender (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1413:44)
at cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1574:34)
at ResponseCache.get (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache\index.js:49:26)
at NextNodeServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1482:53)
at C:\react-app\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1003:121 {

code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL',
input: 'testdomain1.com'

Can u provide an example of how youre doing the post request?

const postApi = async (requestData) => {
try {
const response = await fetch("https://testdomain.com/", {
method: "POST",
cache: "no-store",
credentials: "include",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
Authorization: Basic token,
},
body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
});
const data = await response.json();
return data;
} catch (error) {
return { message: error.message, statusCode: 500 };
}
